# PHP include file that includes a file up the directory tree

Tags: php

I have this directory tree:

```
test.php
foodir
`---- foo.php
bardir
`---- bar.php
```

When I open test.php, I include foo.php. Then, I want foo.php to include bar.php.

test.php:

```
include 'foodir/foo.php';
```

foo.php:

```
include '../bardir/bar.php';
```

However, when I open test.php, I get:

> Warning: include(../bardir/bar.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I noticed that if I change my directory tree to:

```
test.php
foodir
`---- foo.php
 ---- bardir
      `---- bar.php
```

And then change foo.php to:

```
include 'bardir/bar.php';
```

Everything works. It appears that I can include files relative to the currently included file.
However, **why am I not able to travel up the directory tree of that file?**

**Edit:**

I know that I can put `include 'bardir/bar.php'` in **foo.php**. It would search for bar.php in the location of test.php. However, that doesn't solve my problem if I include foo.php from a file in a directory other than the one where test.php is. That's because in that other directory, `bardir/bar.php` wouldn't exist.

Comment: I don't know why..  I had the same issues again and again. I solved the problem that I include only with the magic constant `__DIR__`. I think that the problem is the `$SERVER['WEB_ROOT']` which is maybe the start point for every include

Comment: includes are not relative to the folder of the file where they're included, but to the include path defined within your php.ini config file, and (typically, because the first entry in that path list is a ".") the current working directory (typically the folder for the main script that is being executed)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `include 'foodir/foo.php';` that file is now basically running in the "scope" of `test.php`.

Therefore, the include inside that file `include '../bardir/bar.php'`;

will go up one folder and THEN searching for bardir, which isnt there:
(it's looking for this arrangement:)

```
parent/test.php
parent/foodir
      `---- foo.php
bardir
   `---- bar.php
```

so, the correct include to use inside `foo.php` would be `include 'bardir/bar.php';`

in short: If you open `test.php` all include-paths used in any included file should be relative to the location of `test.php` - not to their actual location.

ps.: As mentioned in the comments: Includes are first checking the defined include-dir, only if there isn't a match, the path is considered "relative".

Comment: As of your edit: Yes, that's the point - and that's why almost all websites just manage `everything` through their index.php file. Because then, you don't have the problem, that you access the same file from different "folder-depths" which allows you to design all includes relative to index.php. (Even for ajax calls you frequently can see that the access is somehow proxied through the index.php) (Just seeing paths like `/comment/45568/question.php` doesn't mean thats a physical path. That's Url-Rewriting about 95% of the time)

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
include dirname(__DIR__).'/bardir/bar.php';
```

`__DIR__` is the absolute directory path of the file where this constant is used/called (no matter where it's included from), thus `__DIR__` is equal to `/full/absolute/path/foodir`. and `dirname(__DIR__)` goes one directory up of the path so `dirname(__DIR__)` `/full/absolute/path`, and where the `bar.php` resides is `/full/absolute/path/bardir`. That's what we want, that's what we get.

This way you don't have to worry include path relativity. It will work any case, no matter where `foodir/foo.php` is included from

Answer (score 0):

> "When you use `include` it assume the base directory to look for
>   file is the directory of current file"

So when you have to include file from the another dir you have to specify the relative path from parent directory as here `"Base"` to include so let say for

```
Base -> A
       ->file1.php
      ->B
       ->file1.php
```

we will use

```
include "../A/file1.php";
```

for Adding files from A and vice-versa.

Assume `../` as the one level up of specified dir

also you can use `__DIR__` like build in constants for getting the dir name of current file